# Unable to match and create nodes using MATCH and MERGE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a hierarchy of nodes by, first, finding any existing nodes (using MATCH) and then creating the relationship by either reusing the existing nodes or creating new ones if any of the nodes don't exist (using MERGE).

Can someone please explain why this snippet of code doesn't do anything:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc(...) YIELD row
MATCH (t:Taxonomy {key:row.TermKey})
MATCH (tp:Taxonomy {key:row.ParentKey})
MERGE (t)-[:CHILD_OF]->(tp)
```

But this one does the job:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc(...) YIELD row
MERGE (t:Taxonomy {key:row.TermKey})
MERGE (tp:Taxonomy {key:row.ParentKey})
MERGE (t)-[:CHILD_OF]->(tp)
```

I am looking at the Neo4j manual and their example does exactly, but doesn't work for me for some reason.
[Neo4j manual screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTBrx.png)

Comment: your snippets are the same.

Comment: Apparently their are not, because I get different results.

Answer (score 2):

MATCH clause just looks if a node or a pattern exists if it finds one it returns the node or the pattern, it does not create nodes or patterns, on the other hand,
MERGE clause looks for a node or a pattern and if it does not exist it creates one.

Comment: Thanks Fabisch. Basically, the only time the MATCH/MERGE scenario would work, if both nodes would already exist in the database; but if at least one of them doesn't the MERGE doesn't create the relationship. Correct?

Comment: MERGE will still create it. Consider MATCH as a read operation only and MERGE is a read and write operation.

Comment: Strange, because the first statement doesn't create anything.

Comment: I think you're talking about different merges. Fabisch is talking about the MERGE of the node, which is correct in that the node will be created if it doesn't exist. Roman is talking about the MERGE of the relationship even if the MATCHes didn't find one node or the other, and is correct that it won't do anything. There's no such thing as dangling relationships in Neo4j, both nodes must exist, so it is impossible to create a relationship where only one of the two nodes was matched.